# CakePHP Bake - Issues with underscores in Table Names

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model, cakephp-bake

I am trying to bake a model that uses a table called "forecast_counties". I cannot for the life of me get the automated bake process to use this table.

I've tried the following:

```
"cake bake all forecast_county"
```

"Fatal error: Class 'ForecastCounty' not found in ../cake/console/libs/bake.php on line 162"

```
"cake bake all ForecastCounty"
```

"Fatal error: Class 'ForecastCounty' not found in ../cake/console/libs/bake.php on line 162"

I'm pretty sure the model names are supposed to be singular... why can't I get the forecast_counties table/model to bake?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cake bake all
```

Then select the model from the list you want to bake.

Alternatively you can do

```
cake bake all forecast_counties
```

You have to use the same name as that of the table whose model you wish to bake.

Comment: When try either of your suggestions, I get the same error: "Fatal error: Class 'ForecastCounty' not found in ../cake/console/libs/bake.php on line 162"

Comment: Do you get a list of table/model names when you run the "cake bake all" command? Something like Possible Models based on your current database?

Comment: I do, one of the options listed is "ForecastCounty" and even if I choose that option and proceed forward I still get the dreaded line 162 error.